# IMG keeps zooming on slider full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, bootstrap-4

I would like to know how to keep image in the sliders to show full size in full screen mode. Whenever it is not in full screen the full image shows and when it is its cuts the top and bottom.

I have tried to resize image do you have any suggestions?

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('venveo-609390-unsplash.jpg')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>First Slide</h3>
        <p>This is a description for the first slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
    <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080')">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3>Second Slide</h3>
        <p>This is a description for the second slide.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the images to be full size in both full screen and minimized.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please, add to the question what libraries you use, what css you apply. It would be easier for the community to help you, if you could provide a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) or a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery) that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: I used boostrap 4, bootstrap.css.map the folowing css was used: 
.carousel-item {
  height: 65vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}